# Windows Phone 7 Event Invoke?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to handle events with Visual Studio C# like I did with my Windows Form, so for example:

On my Windows Phone 7 my code looks like this:

```
//ASDF.CS CLASS  

public delegate void SignedOn(string Screenname);

public event SignedOn SO;

public void dataIncoming(string packet)
{
     switch (packet)
 {
    case 0:
        if (SO != null)
                                    SO(m_Screenname);
        break;
}
}

//MainWindow.xaml.cs

m_A.SignedOn += new ASDF.SignedOn(m_A_LoggedIn);


void m_OSC_LoggedIn(string Screenname, string FormattedSN, string Email)
    {
        //Works all the way to this sub then the code in here don't get ran because there is no invoke with WP7

        MessageBox.Show("hello!");
}
```

My Windows Form Code that looks like this works:

```
//ASDF.CS CLASS  

public delegate void SignedOn(string Screenname);

public event SignedOn SO;

public void dataIncoming(string packet)
{
     switch (packet)
 {
    case 0:
        if (SO != null)
                                    SO(m_Screenname);
        break;
}
}

//MainWindow.cs

m_A.SignedOn += new ASDF.SignedOn(m_A_LoggedIn);


void m_OSC_LoggedIn(string Screenname, string FormattedSN, string Email)
    {
         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello!");
    }));
}
```

So is there anyway I can get an alternative for invoke to work with Windows Phone 7?

Are there any other ways of getting this to work on WP7?

Thanks

Comment: Check this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/09/21/765381.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
void m_OSC_LoggedIn(string Screenname, string FormattedSN, string Email)
{

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
              MessageBox.Show("hello!");
        });
}
```

Comment: @Eric - No probs :) Whenever you want to shift data from a background thread to the UI thread (in WP7) you have to use the Dispatcher's BeginInvoke method.