# Return from asyncCallBack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, return, asynccallback

Following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221581.aspx I created an HttpWebRequest.

Producing this code for the Callback function:

```
    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

                using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I got some data in the resultString, but I can't return it the normal way because of the call being async (as one can read here: [AsyncCallBack - Does it have to be static / Does it have to return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228611/asynccallback-does-it-have-to-be-static-does-it-have-to-return-void)).

I can create global variables and safe the resultString global to access it from everywhere, but I don't think that this is the proper way to do something like this. The MSDN just writes the results to the console (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.95).aspx), not really the thing I want to.

Is there a "best practice" or something for proceeding with results form async calls (for using them in other methods that are called later on?

Comment: Best practice is "use `async/await`"

Comment: like explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx ???

Comment: Yes; `async/await` is really powerful and much easier to use than the traditional async callback method.

Comment: Well, I see... Somhow I didn't realize that option since I almost exclusively googled for IAsync and stuff. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058974/request-response-windows-phone/18072726#18072726

Comment: Thanks, but the way it's done in that link is quite the way I don't want to do it. I want to return a value from the async Task - which will only work with Tasks as I think :-/